# Get a string from LoginWindow to MainWindow?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

I have LoginWindow.xaml that runs from Application_Startup.
I'm trying to pass the UserName string from the LoginWindow to the MainWindow.

If you login correctly, the LoginWindow closes and the MainWindow opens, how do I store the string from the LoginWindow?

UPDATE:
I'm trying to store my UserName string in newTest.MyProperty, but it's null when it gets to the MainWindow.

I've left a lot of code out, because a lot of it isn't relevant. 
The code samples:
App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="PasswordSafe.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PasswordSafe"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
         Startup="Application_Startup"
         ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown">
```

App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        LoginWindow nLW = new LoginWindow();
        nLW.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

LoginWindow.xaml.cs

```
private void ButtonLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StartUp();
        string userN = TextBoxUserName.Text;

        using (var db = dbFactory.Open())
        {
            db.CreateTableIfNotExists<User>();
            User newUser = db.Select<User>().Where(use => use.UserName.Equals(userN)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (true)
            {
                if (newEncrypt.GetMD5(TextBoxPassword.Text) == newUser.MasterPassword)
                {
                    Test newTest = new Test();
                    newTest.MyProperty = newUser.UserName;
                    this.Close();
                }
```

Test.cs

```
class Test
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Pass it in through a view model.

Comment: In the code that runs after the first closes that, presumably, opens the second.  You need to show some code.

Comment: i just added some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so far you did good but just one thing

```
class Test
{
    public static string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

use `static` string access the string as `Test.MyProperty` 
**why static?** because where `static` variable gets created when the application starts and it gets removed when application closes so your data will still be there until you close the application but if you dont use `static` the value will be removed when you move from current class.

Comment: I added static, now I'm getting this error "Member 'Test.MyProperty' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead".

Comment: this is because you are accessing through instance, use directly with classname.propertyname in your case `Test.MyProperty` means dont use `Test test = new Test();` just access the class directly

Answer (score 0):

You are setting this field for a new Test class instance. You need to define a static class.

Answer (score 0):

Set a public `Username` property on your `LoginWindow` class:

```
public string Username { get; set; }
```

And when the user logs in, set it.

Then after your code that does `nLW.ShowDialog()`, you can get the `nLW.Username` property and then pass it in to a `ctor` of `MainWindow` that takes `string username`) as a param:

```
nLW.ShowDialog(); // Your current code

var username = nLW.Username;
var mainWindow = new MainWindow(username);

mainWindow.Show();
```

**EDIT** A further hint: Look at using the [MVVM](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100175/Model-View-ViewModel-MVVM-Explained) design pattern, if possible. It makes your code cleaner and a lot more modular.

In conjunction with this, look into using an `EventAggregator` to send "messages" between view models. I can recommend [Prism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx), as it can do all of this very easily and is quite easy to set up.

Hope this helps! :)